# Adding color to Netsuite suitelet's sublist row depending upon the result

Tags: dom, colors, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

Is there any way to add colors to a sublist's row depending upon a condition. I have loaded a saved search to show output on a sublist. But now I want to highlight the rows if the difference between todays date and audit date(search output) is more than 100 days.

```
    var search = nlapiLoadSearch('customrecord_cseg_properties', 'customsearch52');
var columns=search.getColumns();
var sublist = form.addSubList('customsublist', 'staticlist', 'List of properties');

for(var i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){

        sublist.addField('customcolumn'+i, 'text', columns[i].getLabel());
    }
var result= search.runSearch();
var  resultIndex = 0,resultStep = 1000,resultSet,resultSets = [];
do {
    resultSet = result.getResults(resultIndex, resultIndex + resultStep);
    resultSets = resultSets.concat(resultSet);
    resultIndex = resultIndex + resultStep;
} while (resultSet.length > 0);
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','The Total number of rows is',resultSets.length);
     for(var w= 0; w<resultSets.length ;w++){
        for(var x=0; x<columns.length; x++){
            var temp;
            temp=resultSets[w].getText(columns[x]);
            if(temp==null || temp==''){
            temp=resultSets[w].getValue(columns[x]);
       }
       sublist.setLineItemValue('customcolumn'+x, Number(w)+1,temp);
    }
```

I couldn't find any functions in UI Builder API for Netsuite for doing this. Please let me know if there is any other way to do this. Above is the code which I have used to display search result in suitelet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native api for that.
You can do it by mainpulating the DOM on the client script onInit function.

Just keep in mind that DOM manipulation are risky since they can break if NetSuite will chnage the DOM structure.

Comment: Hey Igor thank you for answering actually I am trying to manipulate it using a client script oninit. Below is the code I used on client script
  var trDom = document.getElementById("customsublist0");
  var trDomChild = trDom.children;
  for (var t=0; t < (trDomChild.length-1); t+=1)
     {var tdDom = trDomChild[t];tdDom.setAttribute('style',
       'background-color: '+tdColor+'!important;border-color: white '+tdColor+' '+tdColor+' '+tdColor+'!important;');}
But it failing saying cannot read property of null

Comment: If you are doing it on client script, then just use jQuery to set the rows color, as you would have done with any other html page.